# How to link author URLs in a bookdown project?

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

If I have a `{pkgdown}` website for an R package, I can include the author URLs in [`_pkgdown.yml`](https://github.com/IndrajeetPatil/statsExpressions/blob/master/pkgdown/_pkgdown.yml#L4-L6):

```yaml
authors:
  Indrajeet Patil:
    href: https://sites.google.com/site/indrajeetspatilmorality/
```

And the URL will be present in the [website footer](https://indrajeetpatil.github.io/statsExpressions/):

[image]

How can I do the same for a `{bookdown}` [website](https://bookdown.org/IndrajeetPatil/R-Function-A-Day-book/)?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use Markdown syntax to achieve that

```yaml
author: '[Indrajeet Patil](https://sites.google.com/site/indrajeetspatilmorality/)'
```

this will make the `author` Pandoc variable be a link in the HTML template.

Depending on the theme you are using, you may need to tweak the CSS so the the link can correctly be readable on the footer background

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot :)
I just used raw HTML to make sure that the hyperlinked text looks good with the bs4 theme.